# AVR Skipping Page Message

Tags: avr, atmega

I just flashed a new program into my ATMEGA328p, just letting 8 LEDs blink. When I have a look into the output of avrdude I get a strange message:

```
avrdude: avr_read(): skipping page 4: no interesting data
```

While avrdude is working, a few LEDs flicker and then go black. What does this message mean?

The code I upload is:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0xff;
    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) 
    {
        PORTB = 0b11111111;
        _delay_ms(1000);
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

The avrdude output:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Feb 17 2016 at 09:25:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : usbtiny
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found USBtinyISP, bus:device: bus-0:\\.\libusb0-0001--0x1781-0x0c9f
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : USBtiny
         Description     : USBtiny simple USB programmer, http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
CMD: [ac 53 00 00] [00 ac 53 00]
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading |                                                    | 0% 0.00sCMD: [30 00 00 00] [00 30 00 1e]
CMD: [30 00 01 00] [00 30 00 95]
Reading | #################                                  | 33% 0.01sCMD: [30 00 02 00] [00 30 00 0f]
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
CMD: [50 00 00 00] [00 50 00 62]
avrdude: safemode read 1, lfuse value: 62
CMD: [50 00 00 00] [00 50 00 62]
avrdude: safemode read 2, lfuse value: 62
CMD: [50 00 00 00] [00 50 00 62]
avrdude: safemode read 3, lfuse value: 62
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 62
CMD: [58 08 00 00] [00 58 08 d9]
avrdude: safemode read 1, hfuse value: d9
CMD: [58 08 00 00] [00 58 08 d9]
avrdude: safemode read 2, hfuse value: d9
CMD: [58 08 00 00] [00 58 08 d9]
avrdude: safemode read 3, hfuse value: d9
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D9
CMD: [50 08 00 00] [00 50 08 ff]
avrdude: safemode read 1, efuse value: ff
CMD: [50 08 00 00] [00 50 08 ff]
avrdude: safemode read 2, efuse value: ff
CMD: [50 08 00 00] [00 50 08 ff]
avrdude: safemode read 3, efuse value: ff
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FF
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
CMD: [ac 80 00 00] [00 ac 80 00]
avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
CMD: [ac 53 00 00] [00 ac 53 00]
avrdude: reading input file "CH03POV.hex"
avrdude: input file CH03POV.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (178 bytes):

Writing |                                                    | 0% 0.00sCMD: [4c 00 00 00] [00 4c 00 00]
Writing | #########################                          | 50% 0.20sCMD: [4c 00 40 00] [ff 4c 00 40]
Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.45s

avrdude: 178 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against CH03POV.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file CH03POV.hex:
avrdude: input file CH03POV.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file CH03POV.hex contains 178 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.27s

avrdude: avr_read(): skipping page 2: no interesting data
avrdude: avr_read(): skipping page 3: no interesting data
avrdude: avr_read(): skipping page 4: no interesting data
```

this continues on and on...

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty self explanatory:

```
avrdude: avr_read():
```

It's doing a read.

```
skipping page 4:
```

It didn't read from page 4 of the flash

```
no interesting data
```

Because there isn't anything there that it has been asked to read.

You are asking it to write/verify 178 bytes worth of data:

```
avrdude: input file CH03POV.hex contains 178 bytes
```

And each page (chunk) of memory in the flash is 128 bytes.:

```
                         Page
       Memory Type  ...  Size
       -----------  ...  ----
       flash        ...   128
```

Your entire data fits into pages 0 and 1, and the rest are not needed - they contain `no interesting data`.

---

**TL;DR;** It only reads and writes pages it needs to, making the process faster, and not wearing out the flash unnecessarily.